# Joomla site asks for deleted plugin

Tags: php, joomla

Latest: 
Remove it succesfully, then another component had an error, removed it too. Now it simply 404 - Component not found. Any recommendations to download an entire joomla folder without getting corrupted?

I am having a trouble with a particular Joomla plugin called JFB Connect, a Facebook login plugin.

> Warning: include_once(/home2/btimead/public_html/administrator/components/com_jfbconnect/models/usermap.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home2/btimead/public_html/components/com_jfbconnect/libraries/facebook.php on line 12
>
> Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening '/home2/btimead/public_html/administrator/components/com_jfbconnect/models/usermap.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home2/btimead/public_html/components/com_jfbconnect/libraries/facebook.php on line 12
>
> Warning: require_once(/home2/btimead/public_html/administrator/components/com_jfbconnect/models/config.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home2/btimead/public_html/components/com_jfbconnect/libraries/facebook.php on line 58
>
> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/home2/btimead/public_html/administrator/components/com_jfbconnect/models/config.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home2/btimead/public_html/components/com_jfbconnect/libraries/facebook.php on line 58

So I uninstalled all traces of it, and yet the site still looks for the plugin:
[image]

Anyone has any idea? I think it might be related to permissions or probably corrupted files (I did redownload numerous times).

Comment: It looks like your code is still using it (rather trying to use it). You need to remove the code that tries to use it before uninstalling the rest of the plugin.

Comment: Remove it succesfully, then another component had an error, removed it too. Now it simply 404 - Component not found. Any recommendations to download an entire joomla folder without getting corrupted?

Comment: At a guess, reinstall it, disable it properly using your control panel, then delete it.

Comment: I guess that you are trying to remove pieces of a package that depend on each other. `JFB Connect` appears to be a combination of a component, plugin(s) and module(s). Why are you trying to remove the plugin instead of simply disabling it?

Comment: How did you remove it? Did you use uninstall?